# Why was my flagging deemed "Invalid"?

Tags: support, migration, flag-weight

If I remember correctly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473218/140719) was moved to codegolf, to which I objected at codegolf by flagging it there with the comment "This is not about the shortest piece of code and should never have been moved to codegolf, as it doesn't belong there." The question was since moved back to Stackoverflow, so I assume my opinion on the matter has met moderator's approval.

When today I stumbled into my Flag Weight page I see that this flag was deemed "Invalid" *on Stackoverflow*. That leaves me pretty speechless.

1. How can a flag I raised at CG even be ("Valid" or) "Invalid" at SO?
2. Why is my flag considered "Invalid" while what I suggested with my flagging was done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Looking at the audit trail of the post, it looks like flags get migrated along with posts.</strike> *(See Grace's comment below.)*  There were a lot of flags on that post, before and after yours, on both CG and SO.  One moderator must have dismissed your flag as invalid, then another moderator responded to a different flag by migrating the post back to SO.

Comment: I thought all flags were automatically cleared when a post is closed.

Comment: @mmyers: No, you can reflag a post to see what old flags were on it.  They do get automatically dismissed as valid when you close a post.

Comment: But isn't that silly twice over? For one, _why would an invalid flagging on CG change my flag weight on SO?_ That just doesn't make sense. And that it is invalid despite suggesting what was then implemented also doesn't seem, um, _overly clever_.

Comment: @sbi: Sorry, I can only report what happened.  Flag weight is based only on how your flags are marked (valid or invalid) at the time they're processed, not on what happens to the post later.

Comment: This flag wasn't migrated to or from Stack Overflow. The flag on the Stack Overflow post has a different time stamp and a different message than the one on the Code Golf post, and in fact came *before* the Code Golf flag.

Comment: Thanks @Grace.  It was hard to sort out the timelines between the flags and the revision history, but it looked like sbi's flag came at a time when it was on CG.  He must have flagged it when it was just closed, but not migrated.

Comment: The Stack Overflow flag was at 12:52. The Code Golf flag was at 12:53, if we want the actual timestamps.

Comment: @Grace: I'm confused. What would that mean? Surely you're not implying I was flagging a SO post to be migrated from CG to SO?

Comment: @sbi No, you flagged it to oppose the migration. You just apparently flagged it on both Stack Overflow and Code Golf, separately, to oppose the migration. They have different enough messages that I don't think that was an issue - the Stack Overflow one doesn't look like it's saying to migrate as much as saying the migration was wrong.

Comment: @Grace: Ah, that is possible indeed. ISTR not knowing what to do with an IMO wrongly transfered question and I might well be that I had flagged it on both ends just to be sure. Thanks for analyzing this! (I now feel a bit bad about accepting Bill's answer when you made so important a contribution to clearing this up.)